# Apache Jackrabbit "web repository browser" do not show imported files

Tags: java, apache, backup, jcr, jackrabbit

I'm working with **Apache Jackrabbit using JCR API**. I have exported current repository to a XML file:

```
session.exportSystemView("/", out, false, false);
```

Then, I imported the generated XML file to new instance of Jackrabbit:

```
session.importXML("/", in, ImportUUIDBehavior.IMPORT_UUID_COLLISION_REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Now I can read and query imported files on new Jackrabbit Server using JCR API. But, I can't see the imported files in the standard WebDAV repository browser in the following address (the root is empty):

```
http://localhost:8080/repository/default/
```

so where is the problem?

Comment: what node types do you use?

Comment: "nt:file" , "nt:resource" , "mix:title"  (JCR Mixin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, according to  [Alexander Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/367978/2260172)

> Note that this approach has one drawback: it is currently not possible to re-import a full export, ie. from the root node and including the jcr:system subnode that contains the version storage, since the jcr:system part and especially the version storage are not writeable (this is mainly because JCR does not specify how to import versions)

in JCR we can't re-import the whole backup (including root node), so it's better to add a parent node (e.g /docs) on all files, then we can export and re-import the parent node.